# Purpose of V- of 4-20mA Current Loop

Tags: 4-20ma

I am trying to use this [AFE881H1](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/afe881h1.pdf) as my 4-20mA loop transmitter but I have trouble understanding why they put ground above V-. So at R2, there is a current flowing from ground back to the input V- I suspect? Why can't they just make V- equal to ground?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like some sort of current limiting but apparently it's implemented wrong in your circuit. Consider the circuit below which is given at p.97 in the datasheet you linked:

[image]

In the section I marked with red rectangle, if you join the inverting input and 40R2's top end (just for easier reading) you'll have the following which is basically a current limiter:

[image]

Everything in the circuit is supplied from 3V3 rail which is generated from the LOOP network and the TLV431. So the elements in the circuit draws current through 3V3 therefore Q2. Since Q2 and Q3 form a current mirror, if you draw current from Q2 an equal current will flow through Q3 as well. So if you limit the current flowing through Q3 you can also limit the current flowing through Q2. So the idea is to limit the current drawn from the loop.

The OPA333 controls Q4 as a variable resistance so that the voltage at its non-inverting (+) input equals to that at its inverting (-) input. The voltage at the inverting input is basically the drop that the current (which flows through Q4 and Q3) drops across 40R2. The current limiting level is set by the voltage that comes from AFE881H1.

The idea of selecting ground there is to be able to measure the entire loop current (by approximating the total loop current from the mirror's one leg) because all of the return path will be joined at that 40.2R resistor before `LOOP–` rail, and goes back to the source. The only exception here is the current flows from AFE's output through 11k3, 88k7 and 40k2 because this current flows through 40R2 in the opposite direction (therefore reducing the current by a few microamps) but probably this is ignored.

If you move the ground point to `LOOP–` rail and join everything there <sup>*</sup> then only the current drawn from Q4 would be limited, therefore the consumption of all the other components (op amp, other resistors, etc) will be missed.

<sup>*</sup> In this case, OPA's inverting input and 40R2-1k junction should be shorted for proper current limiting and this node shouldn't be tied to ground.

---

Now the problem in your circuit:

What is done in your circuit is basically to limit the series pass element's (Q1's) base current, not the loop current. Short U2's inverting input to R4-R2 junction (local ground) instead of using discrete ground symbols. That way it'll be easier for you to see and understand what I mean.